# Hide dimension attribute member with no data in fact table olap cube

Tags: sql, ssas, olap

I have a simple table:

ID, VOL

- 1, 10
- 2, 20

Also I have a simple dimension table:

ID, NAME

- 1, A
- 2, B
- 3, C

How to hide dimensions table "3, C" member that doesn't exsists in fact table?

I just want to create 2 cube in project, for example first for 1 and 2 ID values and second for 3 ID value. Create two project with same diagramm scheme is not good idea. Any suggestions?

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can set the UnknownMember property of any Dimension to Hidden.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's not helpfull cause Unknown Member property uses for cases when fact table has rows that does not exists in dimension table.